# How to redirect to a partial view from a controller action that returns partial view result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a controller action:

```
   Function SelectFloor(ByVal selectedBuilding As String) As PartialViewResult
        If oneFloorBuildings.Contains(serializer.Deserialize(Of String)(selectedBuilding)) Then
            Return RedirectToAction("SelectOfficeAddress", "LocationSelect")
        End If

        Dim model = locationSelect.getFloorOptionsForSelectedBuilding(selectedBuilding)

        Return PartialView(model)
    End Function
```

Despite the fact that `LocationSelect/SelectOfficeAddress` is a partial view, I am receiving an error:

> Value of type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult'.

Is there a way that, given a certain condition is met, I can redirect from this action to a different action that returns a partial view result?

I would like to render the view generated by the action that control is redirected to, in place of the originally called actions' view when the condition is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

```
Function SelectFloor(ByVal selectedBuilding As String) As PartialViewResult
```

to:

```
Function SelectFloor(ByVal selectedBuilding As String) As ActionResult
```

Your call to `RedirectToAction` will return a `RedirectToRouteResult`, which derives from `ActionResult`.  `PartialViewResult` also derives from this, but by specifying this as the return type, you're being too specific.

See here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx

And for the inheritance chains:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult(v=vs.118).aspx

and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Try `As ActionResult` instead of a `As PartialViewResult`